# What is the best option for storing user data (userID, username, JWT token) on the client side?

Tags: javascript, jwt, local-storage

I'm currently using localStorage to store user information, as well as the JWT token after a successful authentication. This doesn't seem very secure, mostly because the data can be edited and altered easily.

I need the userID to issue requests to the server REST API. What would be the best solution for storing the user sensitive data on the client side? Should I store the data in a global state after logging in?

Comment: HTTP-only, secure cookies.

Comment: Actually, the JWT pattern is already a fairly secure one.  While malicious users might be able to _change_ some of the data in the token, the server would be able to detect this, and then reject the token as having been hacked.

Comment: How would you rate the "best solution"? Best by which terms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no best option, only different trade-offs.

> I'm currently using localStorage to store user information, as well as the JWT token after a successful authentication. This doesn't seem very secure, mostly because the data can be edited and altered easily.

There are two distinct things here: the user data and the token.

For the user data, I would not recommend to store them in a local storage as they could be read or amended easily by anyone. Some alternative approches could be to use a [Session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage), or just keep them in memory and refetch them when needed. You could also encrypt them.

About the JWT token itself, if it is generated correctly it should at least be signed (the spec allows the token to be encrypted, signed or both). In this case the server will be able to detect if the token was altered, so this is not a problem. The problem is that if the token of a given user get stolen, the thieve will be able to login as this user, potentially forever.

So what you need to do is to limit the surface of attack to a maximum. It will usually be a tradeoff between security, maintainability and user experience. Here are some points to consider:

- An expiry time can be set when the token is created. Set it to a relatively low value (for example 15 minutes), so that in the event of the token being stolen, at least the attacker gets a shorter timeframe to perform any malicious actions
- If it has to be stored client-side, for example because you are developing a SPA that is handling the authentication in javascript by calling an auth API client-side, you will be more vulnerable to [XSS attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/). In this case LocalStorage is actually not a much worse option that anything else, and it is a convenient one. [Content Security Policy (CSP)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) as well as always escaping user inputs can help to be less vulnerable to XSS.
- When possible, using a http-only cookie is a good option as pointed out in the comments. The token will be sent to the server automatically by the browser and is invisible to your client-side code. However http-only cookies are usually more vulnerable to [CSRF attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf).